# execvp not working when converting from vector<string> to vector<char*> to char**

Tags: c++, vector, execvp

Going from a vector of strings to a vector of char* to a char**, was working when the argument came in as char**, but the conversion seems to have a problem and I'm not able to find the difference.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
    vector<string> args;

    /* code that correctly parses args from user input */

    pid_t kidpid = fork();
    if (kidpid < 0)
    {
        perror("Internal error: cannot fork.");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (kidpid == 0)
    {
        // I am the child.

        vector<char*>argcs;
        for(int i=1;i<args.size();i++)
        {
            char * temp = new char[args.at(i).length()];
            for(int k=0;k<args.at(i).length();k++)
            {
                temp[k] = args.at(i).at(k);
            }
            argcs.push_back(temp);
        }

        char** argv = new char*[argcs.size() + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < argcs.size(); i++)
        {
            argv[i] = argcs[i];
        }
        argv[args.size()] = NULL;

        execvp(program, args);

        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Letting us in on what the problem is may help.

Comment: sorry user, execvp couldn't find a matching constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there's no point in copying the `std::string`s if the next thing you are going to do is call `execvp`.

If the `execvp` succeeds, then it will never return and the entire memory image will vanish into smoke (or, more accurately, be replaced by a completely new image). In the course of constructing the new image, `exec*` will copy the argv array (and the environment array) into it. In any event, the `std::vector` and `std::string` destructors will never be invoked.

If, on the other hand, the `execvp` fails, then the argument passed into it will not have been modified. (Posix: "The `argv[]` and `envp[]` arrays of pointers and the strings to which those arrays point shall not be modified by a call to one of the exec functions, except as a consequence of replacing the process image.")

In either case, there was no need to copy the character strings. You can use `std::string::c_str()` to extract a pointer to the underlying C string (as a `const char*`, but see below).

Second, if you're using C++11 or more recent, `std::vector` conveniently comes with a `data()` member function which returns a pointer to the underlying storage. So if you have `std::vector<char*> svec`, then `svec.data()` will be the underlying `char*[]`, which is what you want to pass into `execvp`.

So the problem reduces to creating a `std::vector<char*>` from a `std::vector<std::string>`, which is straightforward:

```
else if (kidpid == 0) {
    // I am the child.
    std::vector<char*> argc;
    // const_cast is needed because execvp prototype wants an
    // array of char*, not const char*.
    for (auto const& a : args)
        argc.emplace_back(const_cast<char*>(a.c_str()));
    // NULL terminate
    argc.push_back(nullptr);
    // The first argument to execvp should be the same as the
    // first element in argc, but we'll assume the caller knew
    // what they were doing, and that program is a std::string. 
    execvp(program.c_str(), argc.data());
    // It's not clear to me what is returning here, but
    // if it is main(), you should return a small positive value
    // to indicate an error
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Have a `std::vector<const char*> argc`, no need to const cast.

Comment: @n.m.: Then argc.data is `const char*[]` which is not the correct prototype for `execvp` (TIAS: "error: invalid conversion from 'const char**' to 'char* const*' [-fpermissive]")

Comment: Hmm, yes. I was under impression that the argument of execvp is `const char* const*`. But no, this prototype would not work too well in C. Too bad!

Comment: Fascinating... the tools I was missing was the .data() and the const_cast, but it turns out my way would have worked, but I didn't realize the first argument for execvp had to be a c_str().  Thanks for helping sort that out!