# Creating a char* const * for execvp()

Tags: c++

Having a great deal of trouble satisfying the second argument of execvp.  The compiler says it needs a char* const* passed where I have a const char**.  I would prefer it made from user input:

```
std::string x;
std::cout<<" [CMD]: ";
getline(std::cin, x);
const char** args = fillArgs(x);
execvp(args[0], args);
```

The code for fillArgs is to convert the string to a dynamically allocated pointer to an array of chars. In a nutshell it looks like this:

```
const char** fillArgs(std::string currentCMD)
{
     //Above this, the string passed into the function is split into substrings separated
    //by whitespaces and each is placed into the string vector called input.

    const char** command = new const char*[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        command[i] = input[i].c_str();
    }
    return command;
}
```

I am aware it needs to end with a nullpointer and took care of that in the code above. Suggestions?

Comment: use `char *const *` instead of `const char **` in your function and the declaration of `args`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly a duplicate but the `const_cast` in the answer is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35247904/1566221

Comment: Yes, that might work.  I had a vector of strings originally and thought it would be impossible since exec only takes char *.  Give me a minute to implement.  Thanks both for the quick replies.

Comment: @rici better to solve the problem without casting

Comment: @M.M: Even if it involves unnecessary copies? Well, everyone has their own criteria, so I won't argue.

Comment: Worked like a charm........ YES!

Answer (score 2):

`char* const argv[]` (and `char* const *argv`) is an array of `const` pointers to mutable `char` arrays. (Even if `execvp` probably will not modify the strings).

But `const char** args` (same as `char const** args`) is an array of mutable pointers to `const char` arrays.

`std::string::c_str` returns a `const char*` pointer to a `const char` array. But `execvp` requires mutable `char` arrays.

---

One solution would be to use `const_cast`:

```
const char* command = input[i].c_str();
char* command_mutable = const_cast<char*>(command);

char* const *argv;
argv[i] = command_mutable;
```

This works in the case of `execvp` because it just reads the strings and copies them for use by the new executable, and does not return. For a function that could modify the strings and return normally, it is undefined behavior.

But another problem is that the pointer returned by `c_str` is valid only as long as the `std::string` object exists. The function `fillArgs` is incorrect because when it returns the pointers in the return value are invalid. (Also the `command` array itself if it was allocated on the stack.)

So this would work:

```
std::string str = "example";
char* const args[3];
args[1] = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str());
args[2] = nullptr;
execvp(args[0], args);
// Not the other program is running
```

---

When using another function than `execvp` that could modify the array, it would be better to create a temporary array for the function:

```
std::string str = "example";
std::unique_ptr<char[]> tmp_str(new char[str.size() + 1]);
std::memcpy(tmp_str.get(), str.c_str(), str.size() + 1);
char* const args[3];
args[1] = tmp_str.get();
args[2] = nullptr;
something(args[0], args);
tmp_str.reset(); // release the temporary memory
```

Comment: tmlen: `execvp` does not modify the array; that's guaranteed by Posix. (Of course, it does actually modify the entire executable image, but up to that point it doesn't modify the array.) "The argv[] and envp[] arrays of pointers and the strings to which those arrays point shall not be modified by a call to one of the exec functions, except as a consequence of replacing the process image." (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html , the quote is just above "RETURN VALUE")

Answer (score 0):

Well, I went back to using that vector of strings after [execvp not working when converting from vector<string> to vector<char*> to char**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247570/execvp-not-working-when-converting-from-vectorstring-to-vectorchar-to-char/35247904#35247904) was brought to my attention.  More efficient that way and easier to read my code.  I was missing the .data() function.