# Pointers - reinitializing a *char[] without affecting the **char[] that points to it

Tags: c++, pointers

I never thought I'd be using triple pointers. This will take some explaining, so bear with me.

I am trying to implement a Unix command prompt in c++. I was able to get a program that reads basic commands by reading the user input line directly into `char command[256]`, then parsing `command` so that another array `char *parsedCommand[100]` consisted of pointers to each "word" of `command`.

So, for example, if the user typed the command `cd Desktop`, then `parsedCommand` would have two elements, being `cd` and `Desktop`.

But now I need for my command prompt to be able to account for several `|` operators, and/or the `>>` operator. This made me decide I needed to use char `**indiCommand[55]` to point to each command separated by these operators.

Here is the code for command parsing using `**indiCommand` but not yet implementing the `|` or `>>` checks (so this code is basically what I had before, which worked just fine for simple commands):

```
void parseCommand(char command[], char **indiCommand[], int & nCommands, bool & oRedirect) {
    nCommands = 1;
    char *parsedCommand[100];

    //reading the entire command line until its end
    while (*command != '\0') {

        //set all white space to end-of-string character, 
            //so that each cstring pointed to by *parsedCommand[] will contain only one word
        while (*command == ' ' || *command == '\t' || *command == '\n') {
            *command = '\0';
            command++;
        }


        //set *parsedCommand[]'s current iterator to the next word of the command line, and advance both iterators

        *parsedCommand = command;
        parsedCommand++;
        while (*command != '\0' && *command != ' ' && *command != '\t' && *command != '\n') {
            command++;
        }

    }

    //end pointer arrays with an end-of-string character
    *parsedCommand = '\0';
    *indiCommand = parsedCommand[0]
    indiCommand++;
    *indiCommand = '\0';
}
```

and here is my attempt at handling the `>>` check:

```
    if (*command == '>' && *command+1 == '>') {
        *parsedCommand = '\0';
        *indiCommand = parsedCommand[0]
        indiCommand++;
        command = command+2;
        *parsedCommand[0] = command;

        oRedirect = true;
        nCommands++;
    }
```

I imagine this won't work because it will either change the pointer value on both `indiCommand` and `parsedCommand` or not move the iterator for `parsedCommand`.

Any hints and tips here would be wonderfully appreciated.

Comment: Please don't become a [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).  I would suggest you use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)  Would could then use a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to parse the commands by whitespace.

Comment: It might be possible to use vectors here. I can't use strings because ostensibly the `execvp` function I use to execute commands can only use cstrings as its arguments.

Comment: Given std::string myString; you can get a c-string using the myString.c_str(); method.

Comment: @ctenochaetus I would still use `std::string` and `std::vector` and then you can convert the `std::vector<std::string>` to a `const char *[]` that `execvp` needs.  You could even write a wrapper function around `execvp` that does this for you so you encapsulate the C interface.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It's not exactly trivial with `execvp`, because the function expects pointers to modifiable chars. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386791/creating-a-char-const-for-execvp

Comment: @ChristianHackl True but it shouldn't be more than 10 lines and like I said you could wrap `execvp` in a function that handles it,

Comment: @NathanOliver do you think you could give an example of how I might go about this? I've been trying to figure out how to make it work, but I keep getting stymied.